# Can I tell if an iOS user opened my app from a lock screen notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, appdelegate

I have set up my app delegate to get the notification payload of the last remote push notification received. When the user comes back to my app from a notification; Is there anyway to distinguish whether the user unlocked a notification on the lock screen, tapped a banner notification or tapped on it from their widgets? I am using Parse for the push notifications.

Comment: No, tapping on the banner from the lock screen or from the home screen cannot be distinguished. Both come from UIApplicationStateBackground.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to know this. I think the foundation of problem is resolved by simply knowing if the user opened the app from a notification period. you can do that. Parse uses it all the time with their analytics see here https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#analytics. You can also see this in the push notification itself from the console. You just simply need to enable Analytics tracking in your app. You can do a lot more with push notifications see their guide here : https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-push-experiments